# Getting Warning:- org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFSubsetter writeToStream INFO: font subset is empty

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am getting the "font subset is empty" Warning when I run the below piece of code, Although my Output file is perfect.

```
for (CoBorrower coBorrower : coBorrowers) {
        i++;
        if (i != 0)
            maxY -= 30;
        contentStream.setFont(PDType0Font.load(document, new File(getFontsFolderPath() + "CalibriBold.ttf")), 12); // If I remove this warning gone
        putValue(contentStream, minX + 110, maxY, "Name :");
        putValue(contentStream, minX + 320, maxY, "Signature ___________________");
        contentStream.setFont(PDType0Font.load(document, new File(getFontsFolderPath() + "CalibriRegular.ttf")), 11);
        putValue(contentStream, minX +150,maxY,coBorrower.getFirstName());
    }
```

Comment: What does `putValue` do?

Comment: @tilman it's not twice the same font, it's once the regular and once the bold version.

Comment: My suspicion is that you don't output any text. And I don't see where the PDPage to where "contentStream" applies is appended to the PDF. @mkl thanks, corrected.

Comment: @mkl "putValue" will write the text on to the page at the given contentStream, xCoordinate , yCoordinate , data.

Comment: @ Tilman PrepareStream will apend the page with content Stream.

Comment: I have figured out that in the above piece of code If I remove the first setFont statement that is for to bold the text will remove the warning, however it is not the appropriate solution. Please help @ Tilman and @ mkl

Comment: *"putValue" will write the text on to the page at the given contentStream, xCoordinate , yCoordinate , data.* - please show it. It looks like it is different from expectations.

Comment: My guess is that either putValue doesn't output anything, or that it has its own setFont() call, or that there is a setFont() call before the code that we see. So yes, please show it, and check what is done before. Also tell whether you get the same PDF if you remove that line.